# Track order value with Facebook Pixel on Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, facebook-pixel

I need to track the variable value of the orders on my shop with the facebook pixel. Ive tried whats the facebook help page tolds me but when i add the piece of code and refresh my Shop, i get a white empty page.

**This ist my FB Pixel**

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

**Ive added this code above**

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
      value: <?php echo $order->get_subtotal(); ?>,
      currency: 'EUR'
      });
```

And then i get a empty white page after refreshing my shop.

Hope you can help me to find a solution for my problem

Comment: that's why I don't use facebook

Comment: i also dont want to but i need it for Instagram Ads

Comment: maybe it's caused by php error?

Comment: im the biggest php noob on earth so i really dont know

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the plugin on WordPress that name is (inside header and footer) plugin. and open the plugin. after that get pixel code from the business.facebook.com and past in the footer.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see what's expected of a complete answer